# How to display costs in google app engine appstats

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

How do we enable the display of costs within appengine appstats? The documentation from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) says this:

> Displaying cost
>
> AppStats can keep track of RPC cost as well as time. If your
>   application is fast enough but more expensive than you expect, look
>   for operations that cost more than you expect. To turn on cost
>   tracking, set appstats_CALC_RPC_COSTS = True in your
>   appengine_config.py file.

I've tried to do this, with the the code below:

```
# appengine_config.py

from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
    appstats_CALC_RPC_COSTS = True
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```

However, visiting `myapp.appspot.com/_ah/stats` still displays zero values for both the cost and cost% columns.

Visiting the quota page on the app engine cloud console also doesn't display any helpful information, no stats, no nothing. I can however see the historical costs when I click on `View usage history`, however, these are the costs from days previous.

Comment: Try making `appstats_CALC_RPC_COSTS` a global, i.e. take its definition outside `webapp_add_wsgi_middleware`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!